# Jquery hide is not working

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am using the below code,

HTML code,

```
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<div id="one" class="two">HI WELCOME TO RESOURCESUITES.COM</div>
<button>Click me</button>
```

Jquery code,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("button").click(function(){
        $("div#one .two").hide();
     });
   });
```

- the above code is not working.the div is not hiding.

Comment: can you write a code with div tag and button tag...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By separating `#one` and `.two` by a space, you are addressing a div with the class "two" *that is a child of `#one`*.

Remove the space:

```
$("div#one.two").hide();
```

however,

```
$("#one").hide();
```

would do already: IDs have to be unique anyway. There is no need to add the `.two` to the selector.

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
$("div#one.two").hide()
```

"div#one .two" means elements with class="two" which are descendants of div with id="one"

Answer (score 1):

When you know the id of an object you do not need the class or type.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("button").click(function(){
        $("#one").hide();
     });
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div#one .two").hide();
```

You dont need the class name. `div#one` is enough to identify the element. If you want to keep the class name, just remove the space so the selector is `div#one.two`

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is wrong. Use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("button").click(function(){
        $("div#one").hide();
     });
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

$("div#one.two").hide(); no space needed in between a better alternative will be

```
 $("div.two").hide();
```

or

```
 $("#one").hide();
```